# Django Didn't ask for password_reset_confirm template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, python-django-storages

I am following Corey Schafer Video lecture >> Password Reset Email

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),

    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),

    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

      path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
      auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
      template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), 
      name='password_reset_confirm'),
    
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

AND CREATED 3 HTML FILE for these routes

but as per his lecture >> then he hit button (request reset password) he's getting error like `noReverseMatch  Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' bla bla bla`
then he created another route to handle this which is ('password-reset-confirm///')

but in my case
when i hit button request reset pasword it throw me to this route
"password-reset/done/" (with no error ,no email has been sent )

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  config.EMAIL
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config.PASS
```

Comment: It means. that the problem is not in your Code BUT in sending email.

Comment: Did you successfully create app in Google settings ?

Comment: but i also turn off step2 verification 
turn on less secure  app access || yes app created successfully , when i request for reset password by tapping that button (their's no such effort by django to send email) throw it to route (name='password_reset_done') smoothly as i never request for such email

Comment: why did you put `config.EMAIL` in `EMAIL_HOST_USER` ? Put your `email`  at `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `app password` at `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Password email and secret_key are saved in config.py file

Comment: Try to put it them in `directly` .

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggled like me with this email sending tutorial: If you don't receive any email and don't get any error, it seems like Django won't send an email if the email address you submit in the form doesn't match the email registered for the user in the DB (specified in the profile and admin pages).
In other words, I had no errors when I was reseting the passowrd but I wasn't receiving any emails neither. After a few hours struggeling, I just changed user email adress so that it matches the one I wanted to send email to and it worked. (Ack to Elijah Mayorov in utube comment)

Comment: Thanks it's worked ,
after registering username with same email